# How to make the code issues display scroll automatically in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, sonarqube

While displaying the issues in SonarQube 6.4 from the code page, I have problem using IE11 (Windows 7),then selecting the concise issue on the left plane, the source on the right side change, but do not scroll to the warning line and stand to the first line.

- [the IE result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKrjW.png)
- [the needed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3y2J.png)

This work fine with Firefox.
Due to society policy, I need use IE.

How solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the issue - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9555

Thanks for the feedback!